# How to upload a .csv file changing the delimiter?

Tags: python, upload, google-docs

I'm using Python, and with the library **gdata** I can upload a .csv file, but the delimiter stays as default, that is comma (","). How can I do to change the delimiter to, for example, ";" ?
What I want is, from Python, change the delimiter of an uploading file. I don't want to change the "," to ";", I want to change the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the .csv using excel, then it knows its a csv (Comma Delimeted file) but you can set other things to 'delimit' the file by such as spaces etc.

Edit: Sorry, should've mentioned, don't open the file using the 'open with' method, open Excel first, then open the file from within Excel. This should open the 'Text Import Wizard' - Where you can choose what to delimt the file with such as tab,semicolon,comma,space etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you really need to select this delimiter through gdata, right?

Otherwise you can easily change the delimiter in a shell with something like:

```
cat my_csv.csv | tr ',' ';' > my_csv_other_delimiter.csv
```

You can also easily replace these symbols in your python code. It could be an overload if you receive your csv files from somewhere else and you cannot control the symbol you use as a delimiter, but if there is no choice that could be an option.